# System.arraycopy en lugar de for loop

Tags: java

Necesito saber de qué manera puedo adaptar este código usando el método arraycopy, ya que en la línea de inicio del for loop me sale el siguiente mensaje: "System.arraycopy is more efficient".

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            final int size = scanner.nextInt();
            final int[] array = new int[size];
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                sum += array[i];
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: El método `arraycopy` es para copiar elementos de un array a otro. Creo que para lo que estas haciendo no tiene mucho sentido usarlo. De todos modos puedes echarle un vistazo al método y a un ejemplo aquí: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. A veces los IDE nos muestran advertencias (que no errores) para llamarnos la atención de algo que pudiera estar mal o que se podría hacer de otra forma. En tu caso, si estás haciendo un sumatorio de los elementos leídos por la entrada estándar, no hace falta que los guardes en un array, puedes ir acumulando su valor en sum. Otra cosa es que luego vayas a hacer algo con ese array, pero si es solo sumarlos no lo necesitas. Seguramente al quitarlo tu advertencia desparecerá también.